# TextField value is not updated after user's input

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-input, textfield

Just 3 weeks into flutter-dart programming so I'm still a rookie.
I'm implementing a user Settings screen where the user's information is displayed.
The user can modify their information such as their first/last name and address.
I want the user's current name to be displayed as an initial value and as soon as the user modifies the field, I want to keep the change visible inside the TextField until they press the 'Update' button (see animation below). However, whenever the user changes, for example their first name, the initial value is shown again and their changes are lost (see animation below).

My TextField code for first name (last name and address are implemented similarly):

```dart
 TextField(
    onChanged: (text) => {},
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    controller: _firstNameController..text = userRep.firstName,
    inputFormatters: [
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[a-zA-Z]'))
    ],
    onSubmitted: (text) {
      setState(() {
        _firstNameController.text = text;
      });
    },
    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
      fontSize: 16.0
    )
)
```

and the controller is defined at the beginning of the class:

```
final TextEditingController _firstNameController = TextEditingController();
```

currently under testing so I use a user mocking with defaulted values.
here is the app's current behavior:
[image]

any ideas, please?
**edit:** after @AndreaCostanzo1 's answer, I'm adding more info and code portion about my work:
The `TextField` in question is inside the build method of
`class _UserSettingsScreenState extends State<UserSettingsScreen>`:

```dart
class _UserSettingsScreenState extends State<UserSettingsScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKeyUserScreenSet = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final TextEditingController _firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _lastNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _addressController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _creditCardController = TextEditingController();

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.lightGreen,
      child: Consumer<UserRepository>(
        builder:(context, userRep, _) {
          return Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen[600],
            key: _scaffoldKeyUserScreenSet,
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen[900],
              leading: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                  onPressed: null //TODO: implement navigation drawer
              ),
              title: Text("Settings"),
            ),
            body: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  CircularProfileAvatar(
                    userRep.avatarURL ??
                        'https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/848/848043.svg',
                    borderColor: Colors.red,
                    radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                    initialsText: Text(
                      "Press to change",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: GoogleFonts.lato()
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      showModalBottomSheet(
                          isScrollControlled: true,
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return Container(
                              height: 117,
                              child: Column(
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  ListTile(
                                    tileColor: Colors.white,
                                    leading: Icon(
                                      Icons.photo_camera,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                    ),
                                    title: Text("Take a new photo",
                                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(),
                                    ),
                                    onTap: () async {
                                      PickedFile photo = await ImagePicker()
                                          .getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
                                      if (null == photo) {
                                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                            SnackBar(content:
                                            Text("No image selected",
                                              style: GoogleFonts.notoSans(fontSize: 18.0),
                                            ),
                                              behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                                            )
                                        );
                                      } else {
                                        setState(() {
                                          userRep.avatarURL = photo.path;
                                        });
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  ListTile(
                                    tileColor: Colors.white,
                                    leading: Icon(
                                      Icons.photo_size_select_actual_rounded,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                    ),
                                    title: Text("Select from gallery",
                                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(),
                                    ),
                                    onTap: () async {
                                      PickedFile photo = await ImagePicker()
                                          .getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                                      if (null == photo) {
                                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                            SnackBar(content:
                                            Text("No image selected",
                                              style: GoogleFonts.notoSans(fontSize: 18.0),
                                            ),
                                              behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                                            )
                                        );
                                      } else {
                                        setState(() {
                                          userRep.avatarURL = photo.path;
                                        });
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                      );  //showModalBottomSheet
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 30,),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  height: 200.0,
                                  width: 100,
                                  child: Text('First name',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                      fontSize: 16.0
                                    ),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 3,
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  height: 200.0,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5 - 10,
                                  child: TextField(
                                    onChanged: (text) => {},
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    controller: _firstNameController..text = userRep.firstName,
                                    inputFormatters: [
                                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[a-zA-Z]'))
                                    ],
                                    onSubmitted: (text) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        _firstNameController.text = text;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                      fontSize: 16.0
                                    )
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

and the UserRepository mock looks like this:
[image]

thank you everybody in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After you call setState the widget tree is rebuilt. Since you gave us just a smaller fragment of code, I can't tell for sure if this is the portion of code that generates this issue.

```
controller: _firstNameController..text = userRep.firstName,
```

However, from the video I can tell you that, after calling submit (when the widget tree is rebuilt) you are setting back the value to its original state.

If you want to give an initial state to the textfield, do this:

```
initState(){
   super.initState();
   _firstNameController=TextEditingController();
   _firstNameController.text = userRep.firstName,
}
```

And in the text field just use

```
controller: _firstNameController,
```

Also, remember to dismiss the controller when the widget is disposed:

```
dispose(){
  _firstNameController.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since my `TextField` is inside the `build` method of my user settings screen class, and inside the `build` method I call a `Consumer` to the `UserRepository`, I can''t call `userRep` inside the `initState` method because it's not defined there. I'm editing my question to add more information and code portion about my issue. Thanks again!